# Error while using h2o.predict with deep learning as the model in R

Tags: r, runtime-error, prediction, deep-learning, h2o

I'm trying to resolve an error that I am looking at while using h2o.predict.

Here's the problem setup:

```
#If you type class(DL.Model) then output is as follows:
[1] "H2OMultinomialModel"
     attr(,"package")
     [1] "h2o"

xTest   <- as.h2o(xTest) # xTest is data frame in R 
DL.pred <- h2o.predict(DL.Model, xTest)

ERROR: Unexpected HTTP Status code: 404 Not Found (url = http://localhost:54321/3/Predictions/models/DeepLearning_model_R_1449882914034_72/frames/file1ca3d488cb1_csv_61.hex_62)

water.exceptions.H2OKeyNotFoundArgumentException
 [1] "water.api.ModelMetricsHandler.predict(ModelMetricsHandler.java:209)"                  
 [2] "sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)"                          
 [3] "sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)"        
 [4] "sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)"
 [5] "java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)"                                     
 [6] "water.api.Handler.handle(Handler.java:64)"                                            
 [7] "water.api.RequestServer.handle(RequestServer.java:644)"                               
 [8] "water.api.RequestServer.serve(RequestServer.java:585)"                                
 [9] "water.JettyHTTPD$H2oDefaultServlet.doGeneric(JettyHTTPD.java:617)"                    
[10] "water.JettyHTTPD$H2oDefaultServlet.doPost(JettyHTTPD.java:565)"                       
[11] "javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:755)"                         
[12] "javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)"                         
[13] "org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:684)"               

Error in .h2o.doSafeREST(h2oRestApiVersion = h2oRestApiVersion, urlSuffix = page,  : 
  Object 'DeepLearning_model_R_1449882914034_72' not found in function: predict for argument: model
```

Any pointers on what might be going on here? I see that there exists a somewhat related error message in another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34221145/error-with-h2o-predict-in-r) but the proposed solution isn't helping either. I'm using H2O version 3.6.0.8.

If we look at the logs as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34221145/error-with-h2o-predict-in-r), the last seven rows of the log is shown below:

```
065c 4861 a7b3 cea6 7505 00bd fd05 0031
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0048 0000
0068 326f 6c6f 6773 5f32 3031 3630 3232
385f 3132 3530 3233 2f6e 6f64 6530 5f31
3237 2e30 2e30 2e31 5f35 3433 3231 2e7a
6970 504b 0506 0000 0000 0200 0200 a500
0000 4d76 0500 0000
```

Comment: Did you train this model in the current R session?  Or was it saved and re-loaded using `h2o.saveModel` and `h2o.loadModel`?  It looks like H2O can't locate the DL model.

Comment: Here's a MWE: I've multiple h2o deep learning models (say DL.Model1, DL.Model2, DL.Model3 for sake of argument) and they are available in the list "allModels" as follows: allModels[[1]] <- DL.Model1, 
allModels[[2]] <- DL.Model2, 
allModels[[3]] <- DL.Model3.

Since "allModels" is a list, I save it as an R object using  save. To access the models later, I load the allModels.RData file in the R session:

As a sanity check, after I load the allModels.RData, I check for class(allModels[[1]]) whose output is "H2OMultinomialModel", attr(,"package"), "h2o"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your comments, the reason that your models cannot be found is because you did not save them to disk properly.  All H2O objects (including models) exist in memory in the H2O cluster and if you want to save/serialize them to disk, you must the `h2o.saveModel` function, not the built-in R `save` function.  The R `save` function can only save objects in R memory.

To load the models, use `h2o.loadModel`.

Comment: After I do h2o.saveModel and h2o.loadModel, I'm running into another issue which I have reported [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35735675/2288396?sem=2)