# Unexpected error in h2o.predict

Tags: r, deep-learning, h2o

I'm trying to use h2o.predict but it's throwing a weird error. Any pointers on how to resolve it?

```
ERROR: Unexpected HTTP Status code: 400 Bad Request (url = http://localhost:54321/99/Rapids)

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
 [1] "water.rapids.ASTTmpAssign.apply(ASTAssign.java:254)"
 [2] "water.rapids.ASTTmpAssign.apply(ASTAssign.java:248)"
 [3] "water.rapids.ASTExec.exec(ASTExec.java:46)"
 [4] "water.rapids.Session.exec(Session.java:56)"
 [5] "water.rapids.Exec.exec(Exec.java:63)"
 [6] "water.api.RapidsHandler.exec(RapidsHandler.java:23)"
 [7] "sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)"
 [8] "sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)"
 [9] "sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)"
[10] "java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)"
[11] "water.api.Handler.handle(Handler.java:64)"
[12] "water.api.RequestServer.handle(RequestServer.java:644)"
[13] "water.api.RequestServer.serve(RequestServer.java:585)"
[14] "water.JettyHTTPD$H2oDefaultServlet.doGeneric(JettyHTTPD.java:617)"
[15] "water.JettyHTTPD$H2oDefaultServlet.doPost(JettyHTTPD.java:565)"
[16] "javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:755)"
[17] "javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)"
[18] "org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:684)"
```

Comment: could you please add which h2o version are you using and how you are invoking `h2o.predict` exactly?

Answer (score 0):

I use the h2o R package 3.6.0.3. Reloading the data set I want to do my predictions on solves the issue for me.