# as.h2o ERROR: Unexpected HTTP Status code: 500 Server Error

Tags: r, rstudio, h2o

I'm trying to do something with `h2o` in `Rstudio`, but have problems when using `as.h2o()`. It always gives back the following `error`.

For example:

```
library(h2o)
localH2O = h2o.init()

finaldata.hex = as.h2o(finaldata)


ERROR: Unexpected HTTP Status code: 500 Server Error (url = http://localhost:54321/3/PostFile?destination_frame=%2Fprivate%2Fvar%2Ffolders%2F8z%2F29h4lb311gbdhg58mj704g580000gn%2FT%2FRtmpr83spR%2Ffile12ab3b8df30c.csv_sid_a24d_3)

Error: lexical error: invalid char in json text.
                                       <html> <head> <meta http-equiv=
                     (right here) ------^
```

Would you please help me to figure out how to fix this `error`?

Thanks,

Comment: you might find ur answer here in this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34221145/error-with-h2o-predict-in-r

Comment: This may be a parsing issue. Can you post what version of H2O you are using and the first 6 lines of your dataset. Here's also a process to debug your issue or similar issues in the future: 1.  start over 2.  call h2o.startLogging() this will print the name of a log file. 3.  try your failing sequence again. 4.  look at the log file created by startLogging.   If you start H2O directly from R or Python, then you will find a .out and .err file. You can call a function from R to download the logs.  h2o.downloadAllLogs()

Answer (score 1):

This is *super* late but I had the same issue and I realized that increasing `h2o.glm(...,max_mem_size)` made that issue go away. I was converting an extremely large `data.table` to to an h2o object and was getting this same error message.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is when you are using `h2o` to change the data frame to `h2o` format as:

`data_h2o <- as.h2O(data)`

This is internal error for your Server.

To solve this problem you can **restart** your server and run it again. I hope this can help you...

Comment: How do you restart the server without losing the previous objects? I'm using RStudio as well (library h2o)

Comment: Were you able to get around this issue?